# Which preposition should I use here?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice, prepositions

Which preposition should I use when I want to covey the meaning of 'until' (defining the end of an extent or an action from a certain point) but not referring to time but an actual stuff?

It's so confusing since in my native language we just use the same preposition no matter if it's time, page, or place.

Which preposition should I use in the place where I used 'until'?

For example:

> I read **until** page 50.
>
> I solved **until** question number 6.
>
> You need to fill out (the form) **until** the 5th box.

Answer (score 3):

[up to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/up-to) is probably the best documented preposition that is appropriate for numbered things, but people also use **up till**, **as far as** and **until**.

Comment: One other that might get used: **up through**, as in: _You need to feel out the form up through the fifth box_. Sometimes, if the meaning is _up through_, the speaker might say **up to and including**, just to eliminate any ambiguity about whether or not the "up to" is inclusive (since "Up to Question 6" could mean 1-5, or it could mean 1-6).

Comment: @J.R. **through** and **up through** are AmE: they are not used in BrE.